# Passing parameters in ajax call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to make an ajax call to the controller method. without parameter it works fine. Once i add the parameter i always receive a null parameter to the cotroller. I think i have correctly done the parameter passing in ajax call.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#lstStock').change(function () {
                var serviceURL = '<%= Url.Action("GetStockPrice", "Delivery") %>';
                var dropDownID = $('select[id="lstStock"] option:selected').val();
             alert(dropDownID); // here i get the correct selected ID
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: serviceURL,
                    data: '{"stockID":"' + dropDownID + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: successFunc,
                    error: errorFunc
                });

                function successFunc(data, status) {

                    alert(data.Result);


                }

                function errorFunc() {
                    alert('error');
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetStockPrice()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("GetStockPrice")]
        public ActionResult GetStockPrice1(string stockID)//I get the null parameter here
        {
            DeliveryRepository rep = new DeliveryRepository();
            var value = rep.GetStockPrice(stockID);
            return Json(new { Result = value }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because you are treating the data as a string

```
data: '{"stockID":"' + dropDownID + '"}',
```

you can change it to:

```
data: { stockID: dropDownID },
```

in some cases, depending on the parameter declared in your controller method, you need to serialize the data. If you need to do that then this is how you would do it:

```
var o = { argName: some_value };
$.ajax({
    // some other config goes here
    data: JSON.stringify(o),
});
```

Comment: with your solution i also had to remove  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" then only it started working. any idea?

Comment: You need the `contentType: "application/json"` when doing stringify to tell the browser to, well, send the data as json. The default contentType will work when passing in data such as `{ stockID: dropDownID }` as it's interpreted as a valid json object/data.

Answer (score 3):

try `data: { stockID : dropDownID},`

```
$('#lstStock').change(function () {
    var serviceURL = '<%= Url.Action("GetStockPrice", "Delivery") %>';
    var dropDownID = $('select[id="lstStock"] option:selected').val(); 
                     // $(this).val(); is better
         alert(dropDownID); // here i get the correct selected ID
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceURL,
                data: { stockID : dropDownID},
                ....
```

Comment: with your solution i also had to remove  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" then only it started working. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying:

```
data: { stockID : dropDownID },
```

It looks like you're passing up `"stockID"` not `stockID`.
A good tool to use for this is Fiddler, it will allow you to see if the Controller action is hit and what data was sent upto the server.

Comment: with your solution i also had to remove  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" then only it started working. any idea?